# MySQL connector v.6.3.6 problem with GUID type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, guid

I am having a table with identifier **GUID** in mysql (**binary 16**).
To execute CRUD operations i use **EF** driver that comes with the installation of mysql connector **v.6.3.6**.
When trying to insert a new object through **EF** it fails with error {"Data too long for column '**MyIdentifierColumnId**' at row 1"}

**MyIdentifierColumnId** is **binary 16** and translated as **GUID** in **.NET**. So the length should not be an issue.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html
Columns defined as binary(16) or char(36) are treated as old guids. In the new version UUID are introduced and if we want to use Old Guids=true in the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was very helpful, thanks. But I had problems by adding this "Old Guids=true" I was not shore how and where to add it, my connection was failing. So it might be helpful for others to have this piece of code:

```
 string connectionString;
 connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
 database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";Old Guids=true;";

 connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```